# WPF Object => Window DataBinding for add/edit/ purpose

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working on a project where I want to create windows for certain object types for adding/editing purpose. I couldn't quiet accomplish doing this the way I want it. I have created the UI and using two way binding and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for things like name, required and it worked. What I couldn't do is making binding OneWay and triggering source update when Save button is clicked.

I know that it can be done by calling UpdateSource of each binding. But I guess there should be an easier way to do this by something like this.DataContext.UpdateSource() etc. for the entire window. I am setting DataContext of window to InputDefinition object after creating window object and before calling its show function.

I am not looking for a complete code for solution. Although I couldn't find a good solution, I feel like this should be a very common use case. Just point me the direction and I will take from there.

Ex:

```
public class InputDefinition
{
  string name;
  bool required;
  ObservableCollection<Column> columns;
}
public class Column{
  string name;
  string dataType;
}
```

Window:textbox for name, checkbox for required, listview for columns (with textbox name and combobox dataType) and a button for saving changes.

```
Name:     ################
Required: #         |SAVE|
Id  Name        DataType
#   ####        ########
#   ####        ########
#   ####        ########
#   ####        ########
```

---

### MY CURRENT SOLUTION

Following code works for what I am trying to do. But there should be an easier way. What if my Class/Window (view for the class) had 10s of user controls with bindings? Any recommendation on this?

```
private void SaveInputDefinition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NameTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    FileMatchTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    RequiredCheckBox.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty).UpdateSource();
    Columns.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```